# Selecionar todas as pessoas que tem a data de aniversario superios a 2000

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando selecionar todas as pessoas que tem a data de aniversario superios a 2000
Essa data tem q ser com precisão levando em consideração o dia e o mes, e nao simplesmente diminuindo o ano!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Como fazer

```
SELECT *
FROM usuarios
WHERE YEAR(nascimento) > 2000
```

---

#### Como filtrar partes de uma data

Utilize as funções `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` que pegam **ANO, MÊS, DIA** do campo data:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE YEAR(nascimento) = '2000' AND MONTH(nascimento) = '07' AND DAY(nascimento) = '07'
```

Caso tenha mais de 1 valor:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE YEAR(nascimento) = '2018' AND MONTH(nascimento) IN ('07','09','11')
```

Em um intervalo sequencial:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE YEAR(nascimento) = '2018' AND MONTH(nascimento) BETWEEN '05' AND '12'
```

---

### Funcionando no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kP7BfuDokbAJQL9koxF6ym/0)

como nosso amigo postou nos comentários.

---

#### Links úteis

[MySQL - Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Fiz um [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kP7BfuDokbAJQL9koxF6ym/0) se quiser adicionar na resposta.

Comment: @fernandosavio opa claro! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer assim

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nascimento >= 2000
```

Comment: Assim não funciona porque teria que ter novamente o campo depois do `OR` para fazer a comparação. E se fosse pra incluir também 2000, seria só colocar `>= 2000`.